# How to get the value of a var on html after onclick fired?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

On a nav bar I am trying to close a tab with `onclick="dismiss(tabName);`
. I am able to close the tab named Paris if I add the div name on the onclick javascript function `onclick="dismiss('Paris');`.

But this enables me to close only the tab Paris. I would like to close any tab that are open.

How can I dynamically receive the value of the current active tab, and pass this to `onclick="dismiss(tabName);` to enable me to close any tab?

Working example here https://jsfiddle.net/av2o94bL/

This is the javascript function:

```
function openCity(evt, cityName, ThirdValue) {
  // Declare all variables
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
   }

  // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }

  // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  var text = document.getElementById(cityName);
  text.innerHTML = text.innerHTML.replace('{var}',thirdValue);

}
function dismiss(cityName)
    {
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display='none';
};
```

and this is the html:

```
<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London', 'capital')">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris', 'France')">Paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo', 'Japan')">Tokyo</a></li>
  <li><a id="dismiss"  class="tablinks" onclick="dismiss('Paris');"><b>close tab</b></li>
</ul>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the {var} city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of {var}</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of {var}.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't put <script>document.write(ThirdValue)</script> everywhere in your code. Your code needs to be rewritten.

Comment: Sorry, this was an old version, I already replaced for {var}. I am going to update my working example on this question.

Comment: @DamienGold just finished editing, fixed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the name of the current tab in a variable

```
var currentTab = null;

function openCity(evt, cityName, ThirdValue) {
   ...
   currentTab = cityName;
}

function dismiss()
{
   document.getElementById(currentTab).style.display='none';
};
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/cxwqrdgp/9/

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question itself. You are already setting the other tabs inactive apart from the current one. You can simply use the variable to store this or you can simply have a method to get the active tab like this

```
function getActiveTab(){
    var tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      if(tabcontent[i].style.display!=="none"){
            return tabcontent[i].id;
      }
    }
}
```